# SARS-COV-2 detectability versus viability

Tags: immunology, virology, coronavirus, infectious-diseases

This week (#47 of 2020) two meta-reviews were published in the Lancet.

[Ct values and infectivity of SARS-CoV-2 on surfaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1473-3099(20)30883-5), a brief review published on 19 November in The Lancet Infectious Diseases, observed that culturable virus samples are correlated with Ct values of 29·3 (steel surface) or 29·5 (plastic surface), whereas Ct values of 32·5 (steel surface) or 32·7 (plastic surface) correlate with the detection of non-culturable virus.

[SARS-CoV-2, SARS-CoV, and MERS-CoV viral load dynamics, duration of viral shedding, and infectiousness: a systematic review and meta-analysis](https://doi.org/10.1016/S2666-5247(20)30172-5), published on 19 November in The Lancet Microbe, furthers this observation and concludes that by such metrics individuals infected with SARS-CoV-2 are not infectious after day 9.

Does this suggest an upper bound of nine days for viable virus in a standard environment (22°C, 40-60% RH) or may surface conditions be more hospitable than living cells?